# Used keytool to create keystore & key but cant find where it is

Tags: keystore, keytool

I used the JDK's keytool to generate an RSA key for use with an Android app via phonegap build by Adobe.

In my Windows 7 cmd line I added:
    keytool -genkey -v -keystore andy.keystore -alias andy -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
All went well except that despite me, andy, being a user on my machine I cannot find the .keystore file or space anywhere.
So I repeated the procedure thinking it hadn't worked properly but this time it told me that the keystore with that alias already exists.
I have looked very carefully in my (users) folder/s in fact I have searched my entire machine for anything remotely resembling a .keystore file. Can you tell me where it may be on my system?

Comment: Same issue for me on Windows 8, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generates the keystore file from the location, you run the command.
Also make sure that the current path is writable for the java keytool.